# Surjectivity and injectivity of $\lceil n/2\rceil$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Problem: is this one-to-one, onto, or both?
>   $$f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z; n \mapsto \left\lceil \frac n2\right\rceil$$

With help I arrived at the answer is that $f$ is onto.

However, I'm confused in the way this was shown to me. Here's what I was shown:
$f(1) = f(2)$
"Ceiling rounds to the least integer greater than or equal to $x$" by definition. Wouldn't in this case $n = 2$? Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: You should specify the domain and range of $f$. Without it both properties are meaningless.

Comment: Sorry I left that off. Domain x is the set of all integers and the codomain y is the set of all integers. @AlexR

Comment: In a problem like this, there is no meaning in trying to solve it if you don't understand what a one-to-one (injective) and onto (surjective) function is. So the first thing you should do is to look the definitions up and understand them. If you understood the definitions you should easily be able to see that the function isn't one-to-one. (This is not intended as to be rude, it is just important always to know in mathematics what you are trying to show).

Comment: @Eff thanks for your comment and I agree, the definition and how it applied was confusing as I tried to show in the question that followed it. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an odd misconception.

$$f(1) = \left\lceil \frac12 \right\rceil = 1 = \left\lceil \frac22 \right\rceil = f(2)$$
This shows that $f$ is not injective (one-one).

A function is called injective (one-one) if $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$, i.e. different inputs get mapped to different outputs.
A function is called surjecive (onto) if $\forall y\in R \exists x\in D: f(x) = y$ i.e. every element from the range is the image of some element from the domain.

The definition of $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ formalised is
$$\lceil x \rceil = \min \{k\in\mathbb Z | k \ge x \}$$
You can see it as "round up". $\lceil 0.1 \rceil = 1$ and $\lceil 1 \rceil = 1$.

Comment: thanks for this information - very helpful

Answer (score 2):

A function is one-to-one if, when you put different arguments in, you always get different results out.  If it is possible to put in two different arguments that yield the same output, the function is not one-to-one.

Here we can put in two different arguments, say $n=17$ and $n=18$, and the output, $9$, is the same for both arguments; therefore the function is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is onto. But $f$ is not one one as $\lceil \frac{4}{2}\rceil=\lceil \frac{3}{2}\rceil$, but $4\neq 3$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(1)=\lceil 1/2\rceil = 1 = \lceil 2/2\rceil=f(2)$, and so that contradicts the definition of being one-to-one.

> A function is one to one **iff** $(f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y)$
>
> Equivalently, a function is not one to one **iff** there exist $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$ while at the same time $f(x)=f(y)$

Here we have the example of $2\neq 1$ but $f(2)=f(1)$.

As for the question of it being onto,

> A function is onto **iff** for every $y$ in the range, there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$

In particular for this function, for arbitrary $y$ in the range, you have $x=2y$ in the domain  such that $f(x)=f(2y)=\lceil 2y/2\rceil = \lceil y\rceil = y$, and so every $y$ in the range is the image of some $x$ in the domain, thus showing that it is indeed onto.

Comment: thanks again for your input.